# Реализация алгоритма планирования SRR для Q = 2

Tags: алгоритм, процесс, планирование

Объясните пожалуйста, как работает алгоритм диспетчеризации SRR для Q = 2. 
На рисунке показано, что при Q = 1, приоритеты процессов пересчитываются каждый квант времени.

[image: График работы процессов]

Если Q=2, тогда приоритеты процессов будут изменяться по тому же принципу, только через 2 кванта времени? То есть, через каждые 2 кванта приоритеты будут увеличиваться на 2(для новых процессов) или на 1(которые уже использовали ЦП). Или же процесс просто будет занимать ЦП 2 кванта времени, а его приоритет все равно будет увеличиваться каждый квант? Не пойму точно, как работает алгоритм планирования для разных значений количества квантов Q. Прошу пояснить. Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SRR отличается от обычного RR (аббревиатуры для [Selfish Round Robin](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operating-system-selfish-round-robin-scheduling/) и Round Robin) изначальным приоритетом для новых процессов.

Например, в случае обычного RR приоритет для всех процессов одинаковый, потому все процессы получают равное количество времени. В случае SRR ситуация несколько иная: более старые процессы имеют больший приоритет, потому получают больше процессорного времени. На графике видно что задача A заняла два слота времени, хотя на время второго слота приходится новая задача B. Детали роста приоритета у старых и новых задач вы упоминаете в вопросе, останавливаться на них не буду.

Вопрос насчёт Q относится не сколько к SRR, сколько к RR вообще. Q ([от quantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling)) - часть времени процессора которая даётся задаче на работу до вытеснения другой задачей. Если Q=2, то задаче даётся две части времени. Хватило - молодец, а не хватило - тоже не проблема, просто жди своей очереди. Как вы заметили, в случае SRR на выделение времени влияет также приоритет процесса, который, в свою очередь, зависит от возраста и типа процесса (accepted или нет).